# No storage limits using PouchDB + Cordova-sqlite-storage?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins, pouchdb

I've been looking into the Phonegap and PouchDB docs for days but I don't seem to get a clear answer.

Is it correct that when I add the Cordova plugin `Cordova-sqlite-storage` and use `PouchDB` using the PouchDB API, I'll have unlimited storage in my iOS webview?

I'm actually confused since I thought PouchDB was based on CouchDB (which seems like NoSQL). SQLite is using SQL queries for data storage.

Thanks!

Comment: Yea, that is correct, you have unlimited storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you don't have traditional storage limits when using cordova-sqlite-storage.  I've worked on an app that's in the App Store and Google Play today that uses >100Mb of data in SQLite.  Cordova documentation [backs this up](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html).

PouchDB has a SQLite adapter which you might be able to use but I have no direct experience here and the [documentation](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html) notes you should only use it with SQLite unless you really need >50Mb storage as there can be performance issues.

[LokiJS with persistence](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/) might also be an option for you.